# ImportError: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, importerror, torch, fast-ai

On an Ubuntu-based system, I got this error that I didn't have before in an existing FastAI Python project.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/model/predict.py", line 6, in <module>
    from fastai.vision.all import *
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/all.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import xresnet
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/vision/models/xresnet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ...torch_basics import *
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/torch_basics.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torch import multiprocessing
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libtinfo5
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtinfo5. Any suggestions where to find the package?

Comment: If you're desperate, you could try bash commands to brute force find `libtinfo5`'s path